# How to programmatically set view to the front/back?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uiview-hierarchy

I'm working on an application that uses `UIView`s as backgrounds to text. I've put the views behind the text in the `storyboard` but for some reason some still seem to be in front of the text. Is there a way to send these view to the back programmatically? Here is a screenshot of what im talking about[image: Picture]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use on of these two:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

**Objective-C Usage**

`view.sendSubviewToBack(subview)` and `view.bringSubviewToFront(subview)`

**SWIFT 4.2 Usage**

```
view.sendSubview(toBack: subview)
view.bringSubview(toFront: subview)
```

- bringSubviewToFront:
  Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.
- sendSubviewToBack:
  Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview?language=objc

Comment: Thanks a ton! I figured there was method i just didn't know the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`sendSubviewToBack` API is what you want for this task.

> Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.
>
> This method moves the specified view to the beginning of the array of views in the subviews property.

[UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sendSubviewToBack:) class reference

Below is a code snippet in `Swift` lang of how to call this API:

**Swift**

```
yourSuperview.sendSubviewToBack(yourSubview)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
yourSuperview.sendSubviewToBack(yourSubview)
```

or

```
 yourSuperview.bringSubviewToFront(yourSubview)
```